# Sendmail not working from local PHP when headers not specified

Tags: windows, php, sendmail, xampp

I'm having trouble getting my local XAMPP server to send emails via my remote SMTP server.

In PHP, if I put:

```
$headers  = "From: dan@fromdomain.com\r\n";
mail('dan@todomain.com', 'test', '', $headers);
```

Then this works.  However, if I don't specify the header, ie.:

```
mail('dan@todomain.com', 'test', '');
```

Then this fails.  The sendmail.log file says:

```
smtpstatus=554 smtpmsg='554 Message refused.' errormsg='the server did not accept the mail' exitcode=EX_UNAVAILABLE
```

I've tried changing my sendmail command in my php.ini to:

```
sendmail_path = "C:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.exe -t -f dan@fromdomain.com"
```

but this doesn't work either.

Thanks for any help with this,
Dan.

ps. this is on windows.

Comment: dan, not the solution, but there any reason why you must use sendmail? i'd used to use sendmail , but i find the configuration a bit of headache, try postfix instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) documentation:

> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.

As far as your sendmail command line, I believe the -f directive and the address need to be together. i.e.:

`-fdan@fromdomain.com`

Peace,
Tom